# jQuery serialize only part of a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send data through ajax to a PHP script. I know I can use `form.serialize()` but this will send the entire form, which is not what I want.

My form looks like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="timesheets/new" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="timesheet">
<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="xxx">
    <input name="template_id" type="hidden" value="1">
    <input name="user_id" type="hidden" value="1">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>New Timesheet</legend>

        <fieldset>
        <legend>Date/Hours Worked</legend>
        <label for="work_type_0">Work Type</label>
        <select class="work_type" id="work_type" name="row[0][work_type]">
            <option value="Hours Worked">Hours Worked</option>
            <option value="Day Rate">Day Rate</option>
            <option value="On Call">On Call</option>
            <option value="Paid Holiday">Paid Holiday</option>
            <option value="Unpaid Holiday">Unpaid Holiday</option>
        </select>

    ....
```

I only want to send the value of the `_token` field and the value of the `work_type` select field.

**How can I achieve this?**

Comment: Set the other fields to disabled. Disabled fields aren't submitted when a form submit is activated...

Comment: You should be able to grab those values manually and send them over; what's blocking you?

Comment: @War10ck - Thanks but not the solution I was looking for.

Comment: @V4n1ll4 Out of curiosity, what adverse effect would disabling them have in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to do this

```
$("[name='token'],.work_type").serialize()
```